# What can cause GRUB2 to suddenly not be recognized by EFI?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, dual-boot, grub

I have two hard drives in my PC. The first one contains an ext4 partition with Debian, a swap partition and the EFI partition for Debian. The second hard drive contains Win8 and it's EFI partition.

Until now I could easily choose which OS I wanted to boot from the EFI prompt but after the last time I rebootet I can no longer boot GRUB2 and by extension Debian. I can not remember doing anything significant that could have caused this state.

The Debian partition can be mounted when booting a rescue disk and so can the EFI partition. Trying to reinstall grub on it returns a "Success" message but the newly created entry in the EFI prompt doesn't boot and throws me right back into EFI. My motherboard is an Asus Crosshair V Formula Z.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have an Asus Laptop here, so it's a little different but I too have multiple EFI on the same system and have to press <kbd>F2</kbd> on boot to access the EFI/BIOS and choose the relevant drive partition from which to boot. To avoid doing that you can just change the drive order.

If the GRUB2 boot loader doesn't work it is very trial and error but [this page](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/grub2.html) got me the information I needed to get it going eventually. Scroll down to the bottom.